# CDI beans dentro de arquivo .jar não são encontrados pelo conteiner (Unsatisfied dependencies)

Tags: java, java-ee, cdi, java-bean, jboss-weld

Criei um projeto Java para servir de lib à outros projetos, diminuindo duplicidade de código entre os projetos. Este projeto lib é exportado para **jar** para ser incluído nos projetos Web.

Nos projetos Web (de onde essas classes estão sendo removidas) tudo funcionava normal enquanto todas as classes eram mantidas neles ─ a **injeção** de objetos simples e complexos (os que possuem Producers e configurações) funcionava normalmente.

Após remover estas classes dos projetos Web e adicionar o jar com estas mesmas classes ao projeto (configurando esta lib no pom.xml nos projetos Maven) tudo é compilado normalmente, como era antes também. Mas ao iniciar o servidor, as classes (CDI beans) presentes agora no jar não são encontradas pelo conteiner durante a inicialização do CDI, gerando este (famoso) erro:

```
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Session with qualifiers (...)
```

Já adicionei o **beans.xml** na pasta META-INF tanto no diretório src/main/resources (indicado na documentação do WELD e do CDI) quanto na pasta root do projeto e na pasta META-INF criado no root do projeto com o arquivo MANIFEST.MF, mas o problema persiste.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo um exemplo de bean presente no jar e que precisa ser injetado nos demais projetos (e que funcionava normalmente enquanto a classe estava nos projetos Web) mas não está sendo descoberto pelo CDI:

```java
public class HibernateConnectionFactory {

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped @ConnectionBaseExemplo
    public SessionFactory produzirSessionFactoryExemplo() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configurarSessionFactory(configuration, "baseExemploDS");
        ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    }

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped @ConnectionBaseExemplo
    public Session produzirSessionExemplo(@ConnectionBaseExemplo SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public void destruirSessionExemplo(@Disposes @ConnectionBaseExemplo Session session) {
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

O problema ocorre nos projetos Maven e não-Maven também. Alguém já enfrentou este problema? Sabe uma solução para os beans presentes no **jar** serem encontrados pelo conteiner?

Java EE7, CDI 1.1, WELD 2.1, servidor WildFly 8.1